# issue with aws glue can not display the full list of database name

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-data-pipeline

I have an Oracle and MySQL RDS database. I created a script to get the list of my current database name and write it to s3

The purpose of this script is because I have a list of tables from these databases that I would like to move to s3 hourly but for some reason when I create a loop and type in my database name ( the name that is in AWS glue data catalog ) it said database name " " is not found

When I run the script to get my database name and write it to s3 the only data that appear in my CSV file is the default database which is automatically created by AWS glue. The other 2 databases that I had did not appear

The script that I used for getting my database is as below
https://github.com/tramchip/Real_Data_Engineer_projects/blob/master/PYSPARK_SQL_GET_LIST_OF_TABLES

Comment: You have not provided the database name in your show tables command, so it will list all the tables in default database. Also, why are you using AWS-glue/spark for such a trivial job. It will be easier and cheaper to write a simple python script using boto3 library, which will allow you to run/debug this code in your local environment.

Comment: Did you ran a crawler for all of your databases before accessing them in Glue ETL?